# Change the document's unique ID from string to int in firebase realtime using xamarin form

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, uniqueidentifier

My problem is I want to change the document/table unique ID from string to int in firebase realtime database.

This is how it looks in my database:
[image].

I want to look like this:
[image: .].

This is my code in inserting data to firebase:

```
public async Task<bool> Save(CUSTOMER customer)
{
    //var token = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(customer.CusEmail,customer.CusPassword);&& !string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.FirebaseToken);
    var token = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(customer.CusEmail, customer.CusPassword);
    var data = await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(CUSTOMER)).PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer));


    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Key) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.FirebaseToken))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question so your code is properly formatted

Comment: Your code needs to be included in the post, not a link to an offsite resource.  Take the time to learn how to use markdown

Comment: hello sir @jason, I edited it, I hope the format  I posted is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `PostAsync`, Firebase creates a new child node with its own unique ID for that data. The IDs always have the form that you see in your first screenshot, and there's no way to change that.

To specify your own ID, generate that ID in your client-side application code, pass it to the API as an additional `Child()` call, and use `Put` instead of `Post`. For example:

```
firebaseClient.Child(nameof(CUSTOMER)).Child("4815").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer));
```

If the number you want to use is based on the existing keys in the database, you'll need to use a transaction to perform the necessary read-then-write sequence.

---

Since you're considering using numeric keys, I recommend checking out [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: hello sir good evening, I tried your suggestion. But I got this error, CS0815 Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed variable.


but when I use this,



var data = await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(CUSTOMER)).Child("4815").PostAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer)); //but when I try this code, pls see the image I attach.  
[ thats how my firebase database looks like. ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC271.png)

Comment: As explained, calling `Post` will always generate a new key of that format, so you need to call `Put`. Note that my code doesn't assign any value to a variable, so the error probably comes from the code you have around it. For example: you might want to check of `PutAsync` actually returns any value. If not, that'd explain your error.

Comment: hello sir, so If I use the Put, can I achieve this output? just like I show in the image. [My expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQum.png). Sorry for the disturb sir cause tbh as in Im just beginner to this tech.

Comment: Yes. If you call `Put`/`PutAsync`, the database will write the value you pass at the path you specify without generating a child node for it. Did you already try the code *exactly* as I have it in my answer, so *without* assigning the result of the call to a variable?

Comment: oh okay. Yes, I tried your code but I dont like to remove the  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty) {return true;} return false, and Idk to construct the code.

Comment: Please check this sir, https://codeshare.io/YLqdPM 

and also the output , [this is the output which I include comment in my code share link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXd6m.png)

Comment: "I don't like to remove" is had to help with. But the `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Key)` is a meaningless check, since the key will never be null when you provide it yourself. If the write fails, the `PutAsync` call will raise an exception, so you can just `return` true after calling `PutAsync` without any condition.

Comment: okay sir. Anyway if I use your solution why the previous data of 4815 will get override If I enter another data( just like the I attach above in our thread)?

Comment: We've gone well beyond a reasonably, scoped single question and answer here by now. My answer explains *why* Firebase generates a so-called push key (you're calling POST), and *how* to get rid of that (calling PUT instead). If you have further questions, I recommend creating a new question with its own [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that link too please, it's quite useful).