# Data from previous customer got override or update when I entered new user data using xamarin form-firebase realtime db

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms

First all of, Thank you to you sir, for helping me in my previous post, you can check here. [I used his answer which is to use PutAsync so that the document ID will be int.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027543/change-the-documents-unique-id-from-string-to-int-in-firebase-realtime-using-xa/75032776?noredirect=1#comment132439256_75032776)

Since Im too beginner this tech, xamarin form. My problem is when I create another customer, the previous  data in my FIREBASE REALTIME database will get override or updated by the new data I entered.
[Please see the visual presentation, this is my problem rm.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoCFY.png)

And my expected output is when I create another customer data, it will create new record with INT unique ID.
[This is my expected output in visual representation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY3qZ.png)

So this is my codes.

//my customer datamodel

```
public class CUSTOMER
    {
        // public int CusID { get; set; }
        public string CusID { get; set; }
        //  public int CusID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusFirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusLastName { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public string CusMiddleName { get; set; }
        public string CusContactNumber { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusEmail { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusBirthOfDate { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusAddress { get; set; }
        [Required]
       
      
        public string CusPassword { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusSecurityQuestion { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusSecurityQuestionAnswer { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public string CusValiIdImage { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CusIdType { get; set; }

        
    }
```

so I have createrepo.cs file which I put my Save to database function
//save function

```
 public async Task<bool> Save(CUSTOMER customer)
        {
           
            var token = await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(customer.CusEmail, customer.CusPassword);
          


  

             await firebaseClient.Child(nameof(CUSTOMER)).Child("4815").PutAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customer));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token.FirebaseToken))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
           // return true;
        }
```

If you want to know more about my problems or post, just feel free to ask in comment and I will try my best to provide more codes.

Comment: In my answer on your previous answer I pointed to [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html), which explains that trying to use sequential, numeric indexes in Firebase Realtime Database is an anti-pattern and why the push IDs that `POST` generates are a better solution. Why can't you use those push IDs?

Comment: about that link sir, I already read that (the day since you comment in my first post) and Im planning to implement it in my codes but however idk how to construct, like idk where to declare that specific code.

Comment: It seems the Post method is always used to insert data, not the put method.

Comment: @LiyunZhang but if POST sir, is it always the document unique ID is string? because our web platform, can fetch my data.

Comment: Is the `Child("4815")` always be 4815 when you call the put method?

Comment: you can check the image I attached in my post sir. That's my problem now.

Comment: I need to make the document unique ID into Int because our web platform, cant retrieve my datas from mobile if I use the document's unique ID is string.

Comment: What I mean is that you may need to change it as another int value such as 4816 when you add a new customer.

Comment: yeah sir, as sir frank van comments, he suggested me to use the array firebase. But idk how to declare the codes since Im begginner in this tech,